# Netty, SSL and memory usage

Tags: ssl, netty

I am stress testing my Netty 4.0.4 project which is loosely based on the [SecureChat](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/securechat) example.  When I connect 15k clients to my server I see that I am using roughly 800MB of memory!  I've been tweaking what I can to get that lower since I'll eventually need to support up to 100K clients.  So as a test, I removed the SSL handler and my memory usage fell to just over 200MB.  Is this just par for the course?  Is there a way to reuse the [SSLEngine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLEngine.html) or [SSLHander](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/ssl/SslHandler.html) or must they both be instantiated for each channel?

Comment: Would you mind if I ask you to send me the heap dump? t at motd dot kr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An SSLEngine is specific to a single channel. It's not the SSLEngines that are taking all this memory, it's the SSLSessions and their associated secrets, keys, certificates, etc.